# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError when passing dynamic query in where clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to decompose a user's get request and put it in a variable named query. then pass the var query into the sequelize's findAll method using it's where clause, it seems like Sequelize thinks i am looking for a table CALLED query when in reality i am trying to pass the object. I'm sorry if i can not explain very well, but here is the code and the error:

```
var info = [];
//link example: localhost:8081/filter/?descripiton=san+francisco&houseType=house&numOfBedroom=3&numOfBathroom=2&houseSize=500&price=1200
exports.filterListings = function(req) {
    //create an object literal which we will return, and has a nested object named filteredList inside.
    //filteredList contains an array named listings where we will put listings that match our filter inside
    let response = {
        filteredList: {listings: []},
    };

    //now we need to see how the user wants us to filter the listings
    const query = req.query;
    //do some logic where we decompose query

    if(query.descripiton != undefined) {
    //info = info + 'descripiton: ' + query.descripiton+', ';
    info.push('descripiton: ' + query.descripiton+', ');
    console.log(info);
    }
    if(query.houseType != undefined) {
    //info = info + 'houseType: ' + query.houseType+', ';
    info.push('houseType: ' + query.houseType+', ');
    //console.log(info);
    }
    if(query.numOfBedroom != undefined) {
    //info = info + 'numOfBedroom: ' + query.numOfBedroom+', ';
    info.push('numOfBedroom: ' + query.numOfBedroom+', ');
    }
    if(query.numOfBathroom != undefined) {
    //info = info + 'numOfBathroom: ' + query.numOfBathroom+', ';
    info.push('numOfBathroom: ' + query.numOfBathroom+', ');
    }
    if(query.houseSize != undefined) {
    //info = info + 'houseSize: ' + query.houseSize+', ';
    info.push('houseSize: ' + query.houseSize+', ');
    }
    if(query.price != undefined) {
    //info = info + 'price: ' + query.price;
    info.push('price: ' + query.price);
    }
```

and then when i try to pass the info variable

```
listingModel.findAll({
        //error because it wont recognize the variable search nor will it recognize info
        where: {info}
    }).then(listings => {
        // so we loop through listings and insert what we have found into the response (which we are going to return)
    for(var i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
        response.filteredList.listings.push(listings[i]);
    }; // loop where we insert data into response done
```

I want it to find all listings based on the dynamic query but i am getting the error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Listing.info' in 'where clause'
```

Thank you very much for the potential help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to **sort** through your problems one by one. Sorry for the pun :p

Instead of using multiple `if` for creating your filtered list. Use `for ... in`. Then use that array of objects along with `Sequelize.Op` to create your query.

Example:

```
const Op = require('sequelize').Op;

const whereClause = [];
const query = req.query;
for(const key in query) {
  if(query[key] !== '' && query[key] !== null) {
    //object will be pushed to the array like "houseType:big"
    whereClause.push({key:query[key]})
  }
}

//you now have the where clause
//use it in your query with Op.and

listingModel.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: whereClause,
  }
});
```

More info about querying with [Sequelize - Operators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators)

Comment: Mersi Asghar!! This helped me out! I was missing the [Op.and]: and that got it working like a charm!